# Issue in connection to a Webshpere Application Server, where domain also needs to be configured.

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1, websphere-8

I have deployed an EJB jar in WebSphere, and have written a sample code and trying to call the java client.

but it throws an below exception:

**Exception:**

```
JSAS1480I: Security is not enabled because the ConfigURL property file is not set.
javax.naming.NamingException: Error getting WsnNameService properties [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: 0x4942f000  minor code: 3591  completed: No]
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mergeWsnNSProperties(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1552)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootContextFromServer(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1042)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootJndiContext(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:962)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getInitialContextInternal(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:614)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContext(WsnInitCtx.java:128)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContextIfNull(WsnInitCtx.java:765)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:164)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:179)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at com.softcorp.adapter.common.runtime.outbound.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:26)
 Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: 0x4942f000  minor code: 3591  completed: No
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1276)
at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1457)
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1164)
at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1423)
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1886)
at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1379)
at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._request(ObjectImpl.java:449)
at com.ibm.WsnBootstrap._WsnNameServiceStub.getProperties(_WsnNameServiceStub.java:38)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mergeWsnNSProperties(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1549)
... 9 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: connect: Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:83)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTCPTransportConnection.createSocket(WSTCPTransportConnection.java:313)
at com.ibm.CORBA.transport.TransportConnectionBase.connect(TransportConnectionBase.java:357)
at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.getConnection(WSTransport.java:437)
at com.ibm.CORBA.transport.TransportBase.getConnection(TransportBase.java:187)
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.TransportManager.get(TransportManager.java:97)
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.GIOPImpl.getConnection(GIOPImpl.java:130)
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.GIOPImpl.locate(GIOPImpl.java:219)
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.locate(ClientDelegate.java:1983)
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate._createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:2008)
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1186)
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1272)
... 17 more
```

I have tried looking at various resources, but it was of not much help.

**Code:**

```
package com.temenos.adapter.common.runtime.outbound;

import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;

/**
* TODO: Document me!
*
* @author aprashanth
*
*/

public class MyClass {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Test Begin");            
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "iiop://10.94.13.44:2809");
        Context initialContext = new InitialContext(env);
        initialContext.lookup("ejb/t24-EB_OFSConnectorService-ejb_jar/t24-EB_OFSConnectorService-ejb.jar/"+"OFSConnectorServiceBeanRemoteTAFJ"+ "#com.temenos.services.ofsconnector.ejb.OFSConnectorServiceBeanRemote");

        System.out.println("Result computed by EJB is :");

        /*

        java.lang.Object ejbBusIntf = initialContext.lookup(change cell package ofs connector service 
                "cell/nodes/Node1/servers/MyServer/com/mycompany/accounting/Account");
             accountIntf =
               (Account)javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(ejbBusIntf, Account.class);
          }

          */

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Have been struggling with this since 4 days. Help appreciated.

Comment: I don't know whether the problem is related to security issue or not, but the JNDI you are using is strange to me. There is portable global JNDI address scheme since version 3.1 [here](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/ejb-3.1-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/ejb-3_1-fr-spec.pdf) . (See section 4.4).

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I shall go through it and get back.

Comment: @ujulu,  I thinks that is with respect to jBoss. When i refer for other tutorials for websphere they use the one that I have been using. 

http://mrbool.com/how-to-use-enterprise-java-beans-3-x-based-application-with-websphere-8-5-application-server/28063

Comment: Error says: `ConnectException: connect: Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine`, so looks like either IP or port is invalid, or your firewall blocks the connection.

Comment: @Gas, I have checked the port and IP. both are perfectly fine. I have even tried giving it as local host. Instead of actual Ip, but still it fails.

Comment: The document I linked here has nothing to do with JBoss or any other application server. It is the EJB 3.1 specification and therefore, any compatible application server has to respect it.